# How to use a global variable in C when there is a local variable that has the same name?

Tags: c

Here's an example regarding local and global variables. The result of this program displays the value of the global variable `g`.

What if I want to print/use the value of the global variable?

```
#‎include‬ <stdio.h>

/* global variable declaration */
int g = 20;

int main ()
{
/* local variable declaration */
int g = 10;

printf("value of g = %d\n", g);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: i mean that i want to "printf" the value of global variable g ; how i can do that ?

Comment: I don't think that you can. But why do you want to name your gobal like the local variable ?

Comment: If you use proper warning levels, the compiler should help you detect the use of same variable in those conditions.

Comment: And try to avoid that design, it's very likely wrong. The fact that you can do something doesn't mean it's correct, and if I were to encounter such a situation I would delete my program and start from the beginning. Avoid global variables unless there is no suitable solution and there will always be a better solution. And enable the appropriate warnings at compile time to avoid the possible mistake.

Comment: If you even have to ask this question, then it likely means that your variable names are too generic. Nearly add IDEs now have autocomplete -- use it!

Comment: Aaargghhh!  RENAME ONE.

Comment: This has been asked a few days ago, someone came up with an `extern` declaration in a sub-scope (which refers to the variable with linkage, if any). This works (so it's technically not correct that this is impossible), but isn't preferable to renaming the local variable.

Comment: @mafso ,[That was me](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28300252/is-there-a-scope-resolution-operator-in-c-language/28300434#28300434)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access a shadowed global
variable in C?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/618769/how-can-i-access-a-shadowed-global-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pointer to the global variable

```
#‎include‬ <stdio.h>

/* global variable declaration */
int g = 20;

int main ()
{
int *pg = &g;
/* local variable declaration */
int g = 10;

printf("value of g = %d\n", *pg);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it would be a very confusing program. And there is absolutely no need to do this, but you do answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, the local `g` *shadows* the global one.  However, in practice this is more a feature than a limitation since it means you don't have to worry about choosing variable names distinct from globals, and, of course, you can easily control your local names to allow access to a like-named global.

Comment: One can do an end-run around that limitation, even in C. Still, sanity dictates simply renaming the local.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the variable `int g=10;` is just within `main()` so you can print the global variable anywhere apart from `main()` like calling some API as shown below.Else if you want to print it within `main()` then you need to have a pointer to your global variable and dereference it to get the value. The below approach doesn't introduce any new variable .

```
#‎include‬ <stdio.h>

/* global variable declaration */
int g = 20;

void print_global()
{
printf("value of g = %d\n", g);
}
int main ()
{
/* local variable declaration */
int g = 10;

printf("value of g = %d\n", g);
print_global();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is totally fine I don't get -1 .. It would be nice to learn if there is something wrong

Comment: NMDV, so I am only guessing the reason for the -1. `print_global()` only provides ability to print it which meets half of OP's goal of "print\use".  Having an access function like `int *g_ref(void) { return &g; }` would be more flexible.

Comment: @chux I was right in what OP wanted.. print/use meant to know the value of global variable `g` and even though if that is the case this answer didn't deserve down-vote... This is a good answer.. Yes I know you didn't DV !!

Answer (score 1):

1. Only for globals, you can just call another function to access it (and maybe return a pointer).
2. For all cases of shadowing, you can use a pointer you saved earlier.
3. Still, the best option is the simplest one: **Just change the identifier** in the inner scope to avoid shadowing.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the local variable and declare it as global... Since the global variable has scope throughout the program, you can use it in any function of the program. But if you still want to declare the same variable locally then the local variable dominates the variable declared globally.

Comment: I think the poster has simplified the example to make the point.